# Multiple Foreign Keys from One Table to Another

Tags: database, database-design

This is my tables definition :

**User**

- Id
- Name
- IsAdmin

**Ticket**

- Id
- User_id
- Admin_id

My admins buy tickets for the users, I have Admin and User in a Table but i have to get two foreign keys from User table in Ticket table.
Is this solution standard and normal, or cause to low performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, completely standard.  Semantically, the ticket is defined by the user it is for, and the admin who purchased it, so it sounds like your design reflects reality (which is a good thing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,How about performance fro Select and other operations?

Comment: I would not expect performance problems due to this design.  That said, how it performs always depends on how you want to query the data, and how much data is in each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less standard, though it is somewhat flawed, as there’s nothing to prevent an Admin_Id from being set to a "user" id. (This could be enforced programmatically, though ultimately it might require a trigger.)

Performance-wise, it only really matters when Tickets are created (have to look validate the user ids through a lookup in the User table) or updated (ditto), or when Users are deleted (have to make sure user id is not in use in either column in the Ticket table). The questions become: how big are these tables, how often are any of these actions taken, and (if relevant) are there indexes to support these queries?

Purists would normalize your structures like so:

**User**

- Id  --  Primary key. To avoid confusion, this couldbe set to User_id
- Name

**Admin**

- Id  --  Primary key, with foreign key to User.Id To avoid confusion, this could be set to Admin_id

**Ticket**

- Id  --  To avoid confusion, this could be set to Ticket_id
- User_id   --  with foreign key to User.Id
- Admin_id  --  with foreign key to Admin.Id

(Admin is a “subtype” of User.)